# Validate RTMP URL authentication

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

If RTMP URL has Username and Password authentication.

> RTMP URL-  **rtmp://host:port/live/streamkey** 
>   UserName-  **xxxxx**
>   Password-  **xxxxx**

I want to know is there any way to validate whether username and password are correct for above RTMP URL? If yes, Can we do that validation using FFmpeg?